# Issue on C# End-to-End Selenium Testing in Docker: Firefox and Chrome Driver Errors

Tags: .net, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm currently working on a C# application and attempting to run end-to-end tests within a Docker image. However, I've encountered some issues when trying to run tests using both the Firefox and Chrome drivers. I'm hoping to get some guidance on resolving these problems.

Firefox:

```
Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxOptions options)
   at MyApp.Services.SeleniumDriverService.GetDriver(DriverType driverType, String args) in /src/MyApp/Services/SeleniumDriverService.cs:line 24
   at MyApp.Controllers.BalanceController.HealthCheck(DriverType driverType, String args) in /src/MyApp/Controllers/BalanceController.cs:line 19
```

Chrome:

```
Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:45401/
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at MyApp.Services.SeleniumDriverService.GetDriver(DriverType driverType, String args) in /src/MyApp/Services/SeleniumDriverService.cs:line 34
   at MyApp.Controllers.BalanceController.HealthCheck(DriverType driverType, String args) in /src/MyApp/Controllers/BalanceController.cs:line 19
```

and this is packages that i install on my project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UserSecretsId>1808f7c8-1328-49be-b00c-b56fb6dcd448</UserSecretsId>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <PublishGeckoDriver>true</PublishGeckoDriver>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="115.0.5790.17000" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver" Version="0.33.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

and i want to run on this image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
```